# How to check the type of *all* elements in a JSONArray within SQLite CHECK-constraint?

Tags: sql, arrays, json, sqlite, check-constraints

- This is the Table in SQlite:

```
CREATE TABLE document(
   id TEXT NOT NULL,
   data TEXT NOT NULL,
   CHECK ( json_type(data, '$.documentLines.title') IN ('text') ),
   PRIMARY KEY (id)
) STRICT;
```

- This is the INSERT :

```
INSERT INTO document (id, data) VALUES ('1',
'{
    "documentLines": [
        {
            "title": "This is a nice text",
            "lineNumber": "1",
            "content": "bla bla bla"
        },
        {
            "title": "This is a nice text too",
            "lineNumber": "2",
            "content": "bla bla bla"
        },
        {
            "title": null,
            "lineNumber": "3",
            "content": "bla bla bla"
        }
    ]
}');
```

...because the `3. documentLine` has `"title": null`, title is not `'text'` and the INSERT **should** normally throw an `[SQLITE_CONSTRAINT_CHECK] A CHECK constraint failed (CHECK constraint failed: json_type(data, '$.documentLines.title') IN ('text')`, **but it does not throw** (--> the INSERT completes without exception) :(

- The QUESTION is:

How to modify the CHECK-contraint (`CHECK ( json_type(data, '$.documentLines.title') IN ('text') )`) to make the `INSERT` throw an Exception?

- I tried:

`CHECK ( json_type(data, '$.documentLines.title') IN ('text') )`

- I expected:

`[SQLITE_CONSTRAINT_CHECK] A CHECK constraint failed (CHECK constraint failed: json_type(data, '$.documentLines.title') IN ('text')` <-- But did not throw!

Comment: The path `'$.documentLines.title'` doesn't match anything, making `json_text()` return a SQL `NULL`. Which passes `CHECK` constraints.

Comment: Yes, I already know. -But how to make the correct path for `'$.documentLines.title'` that matches the provided json in the example?

Comment: I don't believe you can, because `CHECK` constraints can't have subqueries.

Comment: so, i have to use a TRIGGER that checks the data on INSERT/UPDATE? Or any other ideas? :)

Comment: Verify your data in the code that's doing the insertions? Use a json schema library or whatever to help automate the validation.

Comment: I want to have validation as close-to-the-database as possible. I think i will go for the TRIGGER solution. Thank you for your help. YFI, there is also some useful information on this topic in the SQLite-forum: sqlite.org/forum/forumpost/5b88024c8b